# Populating NSImage in Interface Builder from Folder Reference

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, interface-builder

I placed a folder with images into my project as Folder Reference. Now I can see it in my Package in Contents/Resources/Images/foo.jpg

I try to populate an NSImage like this:

```
@IBOutlet var imageView: NSImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imageView.image = NSImage (named: "Images/foo.jpg")
    }
```

But no image is shown when the app is loaded. I am using interface builder not XIB. Does it make a difference? If I add the images as Group I can use named:"foo.jpg" without any issue.

Comment: See TARGETS > Build Phases.

Comment: I see my folder in Copy Bundle Resources. Does it need to be anywhere else?

Comment: also shouldn't I be able to point to any absolute path with that?

Answer (score 1):

I understand now the inner workings. This is my solution:

```
@IBOutlet var imageView: NSImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let image = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "foo", ofType: "jpg", inDirectory: "Images")
        imageView.image = NSImage (contentsOfFile: image)
    }
```

The reference files are not named in my bundle so they are never found. With the full path it works well.